# Python dictionaries: why and when I have to use sometimes ":" and sometimes "=" between the key and the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am studying the use of dictionaries in Python and I am getting more and more confusing about the symbol I have to use to separate the key from the value, as well as the "" for the key.

Normally, I write something like:

```
user = {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 34, "gender": "Male"}
```

However, why Have I to write:

```
user = dict(name="Jack")
```

...with an "=" between the key (written without " ") and the value? I have another example:

```
def favourite_colour (**args):

    for name, colour in args.items():

        print (f"{person}'s favourite colour is {colour}.")
favourite_colour(Jude="green", Giulio="orange", Chiara="black")
```

Is there a logic explanation, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example:

```
user = {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 34, "gender": "Male"}
```

You've got a `dict` literal. It's the same as putting a `1` or a `'one'` in the source code.

In your second example:

```
user = dict(name="Jack")
```

You're supplying a keyword argument to the `dict` constructor. The interpreter converts the list of keyword arguments to a `dict` when it is being passed into a function/constructor. So it's like you're passing a `dict` to the `dict` constructor and saying "Here make a dictionary out of this dictionary I'm giving you."

Answer (score 4):

The former is a dictionary, the latter are keyword arguments to a function. I don't see how they compare.

It's like asking why you have to use `/` for floating point division but `//` for integer division. You're asking Python to do two different things, so you need two different syntax.

Note that you can call `foo(bar=baz)` also as `foo(**{bar: baz})`, which supplies a dictionary as a set of keyword arguments to `foo`.

---

Note also that `:` already has meaning within a function signature -- it's a function annotation.

```
def foo(bar: "this is a bar object"):
    return raise_the(bar)
```

You could make an argument for dictionary syntax being `{key=value, key2=value2}`, but the `=` operator means assignment and you're not really assigning the value to the key, you're only *relating* it to the key within this mapping. I don't think it fits.